# Forgein key constraint in mysql. I cannot fix it?

Tags: mysql

I created the following table in mysql as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
  fname    varchar(15) not null, 
  minit    varchar(1),
  lname    varchar(15) not null,
  ssn      char(9),
  bdate    date,
  address  varchar(50),
  sex      char,
  salary   decimal(10,2),
  superssn char(9),
  dno      integer(4),
  primary key (ssn),
  foreign key (superssn) references employee(ssn)
);
```

Then I tried to insert the following information:

```
INSERT INTO employee VALUES ("Bob","B","Bender","666666600",
"1968-04-17","8794 Garfield, Chicago, IL","M","96000.00","null","8");
```

Sadly, I got this error:

```
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint 
fails (`test`.`employee`, CONSTRAINT `employee_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY 
(`superssn`) REFERENCES `employee` (`ssn`))
```

I tried to alter the table so that `superssn` can be null but no solution is working.

```
ALTER TABLE employee MODIFY COLUMN superssn CHAR(9) default null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"null"` is not the same as `null`. Remove the quotes.